# Word Length as defined in the .ZIP format specification

Tags: compression, zip, standards, cpu-architecture

So I've been reading through [PKWARE's specification of the .zip file format](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) and have noticed that in several places they give block sizes in terms of words (the processor word, not the dictionary word :-) ).

Now, the way I understand it, the byte size of a word is specific to a certain processor family. So if a file was zipped on an i386 and then unzipped on an x64-86, the two architectures would have different definitions of a word (4 bytes vs. 8 bytes) and would therefore interpret the block data differently.

Am I missing something here? Or do the folks at PKWARE simply assume that 1 word = 4 bytes? That seems like the most likely option to me - I've checked some zip files with a hex editor and the 4-byte definition would fit, but I'd like some confirmation because its not like I have a whole bunch of different processors to test with :)

Thanks in advance, and sorry if the question already exists - I did try searching but it's a little difficult because the word "word" is so ambiguous (see what I mean?)

Comment: in pkware's spec, 1 word = 32 bits.

Comment: Short and sweet, that's all I needed to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the specification says "word" for a stored block in the deflate format, it means two bytes (in LSB order).

For zip decryption (where said encryption should not be used since it's so weak), again a word means two bytes.

When it talks about a general purpose flag word under imploding, it again means two bytes.